# Refresh HTTP session in another server programmatically in Java/Weblogic

Tags: java, session, jakarta-ee, weblogic

Alright, I have

1. Server 1 which browsers connect to, and where the HTTP session is handled automatically by Weblogic.
2. Server 2 which receives events from a third server
3. The user/browser is sitting idle, ie. not making any calls to Server 1 so the HTTP session times out after the specified timeout period

When **server 2** receives certain events, I would need to refresh the HTTP session for a specific user at **server 1**.

The only way I have come up with is this:

1. In server 1, store the session id somewhere where it's accessible by server 2
2. When the event to refresh the session is received in server 2, make an HTTP call with the session cookie to server 1 (some dummy resource), simulating a call from the browser.

But I don't want do the HTTP call (and haven't actually tested it either) since it requires changes also in the firewall etc and in general *feels kludgy*. Instead I would like to send a message (using JMS for example) from server 2 to server 1, and then use some API to refresh the session. But I haven't found such API to exist.

So, do you know of a API that I can use for refreshing the session using the session id, or can you think of some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by: 
1. Using Server-Side push which will in turn invoke http to server 1 from 2. Atmosphere for example. 
2. Have a scheduler in server 2 which will check for that event and send a request to server 1.

Comment: Thanks but the HTTP call is what I don't want to do. I made a little edit to the original post, hopefully it's more clear now if it wasn't previously.

Comment: If not HTTP, try updating a database table from server2. Server1 should be able to access that same table and If you are using Oracle db server you can user DatabaseChangeNotification which is a db push.

Comment: I mean whenever an event occurs in server2 it should update some field  in db, which server1 should be monitoring. Once there is an change to that flag you can refresh the session id of user.

Comment: Even with that, I still have to do the HTTP call to refresh the session. Delivering the info from server 2 to server 1 is not the problem, I would like to avoid making the HTTP call just to refresh session.

Comment: Nope. You don't need to. If you read my comment again I talked about checking a database field for any change from server1 using scheduler or similar.

Comment: You are talking about the implementation of communication between the servers (which is not a problem), I am talking about the actual method of refreshing the HTTP session.